# Would it be easier if duplicates were merged together instead?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

I'm curious what the argument is/would be to have duplicate questions merged together as one end point vs as they are now, where if you hit a duplicate it points to the final end point, or if you hit the end point you don't see any duplicates?

I would argue it may be more beneficial to see responses to other duplicates in the same thread.

Comment: This is already happening as a manual moderator action where applicable. More often than not it's not possible, though, because duplicates tend to be worded slightly differently enough for merged answers not to make sense

Comment: I also like this idea. I think it could be a good way of visualizing all the answers for the same topic/problem. I know some duplicated questions may have slight and subtle differences but, as you point out, when you hit the end point you can not visualize the newer questions that may have even better answers (even if they are closed).

Answer (score 15):

No.  One reason why you would not want duplicates to be merged as the duplicates at as sign post to the correct answer.  There are many different ways to search for the same thing and the canonical answer may not be able to have all of those search terms in it.  Having questions that are asked differently but all point to the same answer should in theory make it easier for someone to find it as they do not need to be as precise in their searching.

If you want to see more you can always peruse through the **Linked** side bar which shows question that are linked from and to the question you are on.

Comment: ^ This.  There are lots of ways to ask the same question - SO should be able to guide as many people as possible to the best answer.

Answer (score 14):

One reason I can think of: it's not done because many dupes are answered before they're closed, especially on SO. And those *answers are also dupes*. This way you are getting lots of dupe answers in the older thread without any need.

Also, a question can be decided to be the dupe only if the OP's problem *boils down* to the one mentioned in another question and not exactly the same, so moving the answers there from the newer thread would make the new answers confusing.

Also, the questions can already be merged by mods. They can surely decide whether the posts need to be merged or not.